# Crontab CD to Directory

Tags: cron, cron-task

All of my cronjob scripts run from a specific directory. Can I add `cd /FOLDER/PATH` at the top of the `crontab` file and expect all scripts to be run from that directory?

Currently all my crontab functions are like this (ignore lack of specific run frequencies)

```
* * * * * cd /FOLDER/PATH && python3 File.py
* * * * * cd /FOLDER/PATH && python3 File2.py
* * * * * cd /FOLDER/PATH && python3 File3.py
```

I would rather it be like

```
cd /FOLDER/PATH
* * * * * python3 File.py
* * * * * python3 File2.py
* * * * * python3 File3.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since crontab file is not actually what is running when a task is being triggered what you will to do would not work since cron tasks are run from the cron daemon. A solution to beautify the commands a bit would be to add the path were the actual scripts are to the `PATH` env variable on the crontab file

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/path/to/scripts
```

and then do something like this:

```
* * * * * /FOLDER/PATH/File.py
* * * * * /FOLDER/PATH/File2.py
* * * * * /FOLDER/PATH/File3.py
```

Note that name.py files should have the interpreter defined at the top of the file for it to work.